# synchronizing storage servers

Tags: backup, storage, rsync, failover

we have a storage server, with currently an amount of about 20TB of media files which we want to synchronize with a second storage server, for backup and fail-over. the facts are:

- we're storing currently about 9.000.000 files
- file sizes from several KB up to 1 GB
- only one-way synchronizing required
- the files do not get updated and there are no deletes -- only new files to synchronize
- the storage servers are running open-e, they are mounted as NFS volumes in the network

currently we use just plain rsync on a third-server to perform the synchronization.

i would like to know, if there are better tools for such an amount of files -- commercial or open-source?

thanx very much,

Comment: I've been trying to find time to try inotify/incron for something like this but of a smaller scope.  It watches a filesystem for writes at the kernel level and can trigger a command of your choosing when the file handle is closed (eg an rsync, or writing to a queue).

Comment: mmm ... sounds interesting, however i'm not sure how failsafe this is? what, if sync-command fails? i would have to have something which can apply the sync-command later again ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might see an increase in performance if you just used a hand rolled script that checked file creation time (and possibly size) and compared it to a list (or registry) of files that have already been synced to the backup server.

Rsync might be spending a lot of time checking for changes in ALL of your files when a check of one or two file attributes might be enough.

We do something similar, but on a much smaller scale, to synchronize photos between two servers.  I wrote a bash script that maintains a sorted registry of files concatenated together with file creation times and file sizes. Every time the script runs, it checks the server that we sync from (the source server) and generates a sorted list of files concatenated with creation times and file sizes. I then use the **comm** command to compare those two registries and only print those entries that appear on the source server. This is the list of files that must be synced to the new server.

Then I just scp the new files over. I have some trapping, locking and throttling in there so that it doesn't overwhelm stuff, but it works and is pretty quick.

The nice thing is that you don't have to sync everything to start if you already have a lot of the files in both places. Just create an initial registry on the target server, then cron up the script and it will start syncing from that point.  If you end up needing to sync a file that you never thought you would, all you have to do is touch it (to change the date info) on the source server and it will sync on the next scheduled run.

So for a directory that looks like this:

```
-rw-r----- 1 example example  38801 2010-01-21 11:45 1.JPG
-rw-r----- 1 example example  38801 2010-01-21 11:45 2.JPG
-rw-r----- 1 example example 757638 2010-01-21 11:45 3.JPG
-rw-r----- 1 example example  16218 2010-01-22 15:07 9.JPG
```

This listing gets transformed by the script into a registry file that looks like this:

```
1.JPG_2010-01-21_11:45_38801
2.JPG_2010-01-21_11:45_38801
3.JPG_2010-01-21_11:45_757638
9.JPG_2010-01-22_15:07_16218
```

I store that registry (of the source server's files) on the target server. Every time the cron job runs on the target server, I create a list of the files currently on the source server using the same format. Let's say that a few new files, 10.JPG and 11.JPG have appeared in the listing.

```
-rw-r----- 1 example example  38801 2010-01-21 11:45 1.JPG
-rw-r----- 1 example example  38801 2010-01-21 11:45 2.JPG
-rw-r----- 1 example example 757638 2010-01-21 11:45 3.JPG
-rw-r----- 1 example example  16218 2010-01-22 15:07 9.JPG
-rw-r----- 1 example example  16218 2010-02-24 11:00 10.JPG
-rw-r----- 1 example example  16218 2010-02-24 11:00 11.JPG
```

The current file registry will look like this:

```
1.JPG_2010-01-21_11:45_38801
2.JPG_2010-01-21_11:45_38801
3.JPG_2010-01-21_11:45_757638
9.JPG_2010-01-22_15:07_16218
10.JPG_2010_02_24_11:00_16218
11.JPG_2010_02_24_11:00_16218
```

Running **comm** against the old registry and the current registry and cutting out the first field (the file that needs to be copied) like so:

```
comm -23 ${CURRENT_REG} ${OLD_REG} | cut -d'_' -f1 > ${SYNC_LIST}
```

Will yield a list of files (one per line) that needs to be copied (I use scp) to the backup (target) server:

```
10.JPG
11.JPG
```

Then you just process that list of files through a loop.

The **comm** command above is basically saying show me everything that ***ONLY*** exists in the first file. The comparisons it makes are also very fast. It's just comparing lines in a text file after all; even if that file is very large. Luckily, you've populated that text file with some basic meta-data about your files and, through **comm**, are comparing that data very quickly.

The nice thing about stuffing that meta-data into the list is that it will allow for situations where the file *has* changed between syncs. Say a new version of the file comes along or there was a problem with the old one. The name of the file will exist in the old registry, but its meta-data (file creation time stamp and size) will be different. So the current file registry will show that difference and the **comm** comparison will say that that information only exists in the first file. When you create the list of files to copy, that file name will be in there and your copy command will overwrite the out of date file with the same name.

The rest is just details:

- Use file locking/semaphores so you don't have the script running over itself if the last time it ran isn't done by the next time it runs.
- Use temp files to store your current file list and your process list and then use traps to clean them up on script exit.
- When you are all done, copy the current file list over the old file list to be ready for the next comparison, but only do it if the registry has files in it (otherwise, you'll copy over an empty registry and sync EVERYTHING the next time).

Hope that helps. This works for our situation quite well, but, as with all things, might not work within the constraints of your organization or setup. Good luck, at the very least it might give you some ideas.

Comment: thanks very much ... i somehow like your idea. yes, rsync is very slow, because of the file-lists it generates for both servers. i'm not sure, if your solution would work for us, because it takes a while till the 9.000.000 files list is generated, but i got an idea of how things could work and maybe i find a solution of how to speed up the file-list generation.

Comment: yeah, the first time is going to be the slowest time. However, if the systems are already partially synced up, you can generate the initial "old registry" for comparison. Then the next time it syncs, the "new registry" that is created will have very few changes (unless you change 9,000,000 files at a time). Because of that, your syncs will be relatively quick.

Comment: after playing around a little with this approach, i decided to go with it. i'm still not sure how to speed up the generation of the file-list, but the syncing indeed is much faster than anything i was able to set up by just using rsync. and this approach is much more easy to set up, than anything else i found, including dbrd and glusterfs -- i'll keep them in mind, though. thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few of options to look into.

Look into [DBRD](http://www.drbd.org/) if you don't need to access both copies at the same time.  This is due to file system limitations not limitations of DBRD and there are a [few work arounds](http://www.drbd.org/home/mirroring/) to access the 2ndary copy if you need to.  But the project was recently accepted into the kernel so support for this going forward should be pretty simple.

Another option would be a file system such as [GlusterFS](http://gluster.com/).  Which can be setup a 2 node [replicated configuration](http://gluster.com/community/documentation/index.php/Storage_Server_Installation_and_Configuration#Configuring_Replicated_Volumes).  I think this would be ideal as it should allow for a better failover and scalability.  MondoDB is also looking interesting for this sort of stuff using their GridFS but it's a bit newer.

Comment: thanks, i'll have a look at both DBRD and GlusterFS. i'm not sure, if mongodb / gridfs is the right thing here. we're already using mongodb for something else and it's a great product, but i'm not sure if it can handle such a large file-base ...

Comment: I don't have any experience with mongo myself but I first heard about the gridfs and using it as a distributed file store on the Floss Weekly Podcast episode 105.  http://twit.tv/floss105